# What does events/EventEmitter do in a nodejs constructor function

Tags: node.js, api, constructor, eventemitter

I am learning node.js. On the nodejs api website there is a piece of code that I don't really get.
The link is [here](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor)

```
var util = require("util");
var events = require("events");

function MyStream() {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(MyStream, events.EventEmitter);

MyStream.prototype.write = function(data) {
    this.emit("data", data);
}

var stream = new MyStream();

console.log(stream instanceof events.EventEmitter); // true
console.log(MyStream.super_ === events.EventEmitter); // true

stream.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log('Received data: "' + data + '"');
})
stream.write("It works!"); // Received data: "It works!"
```

so the confusing part is

```
events.EventEmitter.call(this);
```

What does it do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyStream` is a new object declaration that inherits behaviors from `events.EventEmitter` as can be seen from this line where the inheritance is configured:

```
util.inherits(MyStream, events.EventEmitter);
```

So, when the `MyStream` constructor is invoked usually via something like `var stream = new MyStream();`, it needs to also invoke the constructor of the object that it inherits from so the parent object can initialize itself properly.  That's what this line is:

```
events.EventEmitter.call(this);
```

`events.EventEmitter` is the constructor of the object that `MyStream` inherits from.  `events.EventEmitter.call(this)` instructs Javascript to call that constructor with the `this` pointer set to `this` object.

If you need more help with understanding `.call()`, you can read [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).